# adapt the method with a dynamic number of parameters

Tags: python, dynamic, graph, sage

I'm using sage to print diffrent graphs with a script written in python. I'm trying to write a generic code that allows me to print all the graphs. For example I have :

```
g1 = graphs.BarbellGraph(9, 4) 
g2 = graphs.RandomNewmanWattsStrogatz(12, 2, .3)
```

The graph depends on the number and type of my parameters and I must adapt my code to make it work with diffrent cases.

My code :

```
registry = {"graphs": graphs, "digraphs":digraphs}
methodtocall = getattr(registry["graphs"], "BarbellGraph")
result = methodtocall(2,3)
print(result)
```

with this code I get as a result

```
graphs.BarbellGraph(2, 3)
```

my problem is that methodtocall accepts 2 parameters in the code above and I want to change it depending on the number of parameters for the chosen graph. 
How can I change the code to make it dynamic for the parameters ?

if I have N parameters I want to have

```
result = methodtocall(param1, ... ,paramN)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Because BarbellGraph is just an example instead of it I retrieve the chosen graph from a list : list_graph[nb_graph]. and for the arguments I have a dictionary where I put the parameters and their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [star-operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) (aka "splat" or "unpacking" operator):

```
result = methodtocall(*[param1, ... ,paramN])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the arguments in a list, you can call a function as follows;

```
graphs.RandomNewmanWattsStrogatz(*parameter_list)
```

Which will expand the list as position arguments.

If you are writing a function which needs to take position arguments you can accept arbitrary numbers of arguments in a similar manner;

```
def my_function(*args):
    assert(type(args) == tuple)
```